# WiX user to know checkbox selected or Not

Tags: wix, burn

I am using Burn for installing my components. I am using RTFTheme.xml and i added one checkbox in the options page.

If i want to know that user has selected the checkbox or not, what should i need to do.
I mean how can i access the variable inside my bundle code which is defined in options page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I luckily got it, i created my own theme file with my controls in options page and i got the values.

Thanks
Ravi S